# Ruby nokogiri attribute selector in XML file

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

this is the xml file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:putResponse
            xmlns:ns1="urn:DmsManagerClient">
            <result xsi:type="xsd:string">
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
                <MESSAGE ID="11c73b9e-687c-4300-baba-b743c26f7c83" TYPE="CUSDMS">
                    <DELIVERY>
                        <FROM>
                            <SENDER>0072000</SENDER>
                            <SERVICE>eService</SERVICE>
                            <DATE>2019-03-08T12:27:25</DATE>
                        </FROM>
                        <TO>
                            <DEALER DEALERCODE="0072000" MARKETCODE="1000"/>
                        </TO>
                    </DELIVERY>
                    <CONTENT>
                        <dms:ComplexResponse ErrorCode="430" ErrorDescription="null :  PrivacyUE Mancante" Return="false"
                            xmlns:dms="http://dmsmanagerservice">
                            <dms:Element Name="DMSVERSION">2.7</dms:Element>
                        </dms:ComplexResponse>
                    </CONTENT>
                </MESSAGE>
            </result>
        </ns1:putResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I am coding with Ruby and I used  Nokogiri and the method xpath to extrapole the "CONTENT" of the file

this is the code:

```
def extrapolate_error(xml)
  doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open(xml))
  doc.xpath('//CONTENT')

end
```

and this is the result:

```html
[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x1c5ba78 name="CONTENT" children=[
   #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x1c5b940 "\n">, 
   #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x1c5b8bc name="ComplexResponse" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x1c5b88c prefix="dms" href="http://dmsmanagerservice"> 
     attributes=[
       #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x1c5b874 name="ErrorCode" value="430">, 
       #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x1c5b868 name="ErrorDescription" value="null :  PrivacyUE Mancante">, 
       #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x1c5b85c name="Return" value="false">] 
       children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x1c5b118 "\n">, 
                 #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x1c5b094 name="Element" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x1c5b88c prefix="dms" href="http://dmsmanagerservice"> 
             attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x1c5b058 name="Name" value="DMSVERSION">] 
             children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x1c5abe4 "2.7">]>, 
                     #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x1c5aaac "\n">]>,
                     #<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x1c5a974 "\n">]>]
```

Now I need to enter in it  and select some attributes.

In the specific I need this:

name="ErrorCode" value="430"

name="ErrorDescription" value="null :  PrivacyUE Mancante"

I do not know how to procceed. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work for you assuming the `dms` namespace is always the same

```
doc.xpath('//CONTENT/dms:ComplexResponse', dms: 'http://dmsmanagerservice')
    .xpath('@ErrorCode | @ErrorDescription')
    .each_with_object({}) do |e,obj| 
      obj[e.name] = e.text
    end
#=> {"ErrorCode"=>"430", "ErrorDescription"=>"null :  PrivacyUE Mancante"}
```

You already understand how you got to //CONTENT so from there we use dms:ComplexResponse to navigate deeper but since this is namespaced we have to provide the namespace reference e.g. `dms: 'http://dmsmanagerservice'`.

Then we select the attributes we are interested in `@ErrorCode` and `@ErrorDescription`.

In `XPath` the pipe `|` means UNION (think AND) so we want to select both.

Then we are just building a `Hash` using the `name` as the key and the `text` as the value.

[XPath Cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/xpath) - Useful resource if you need additional reference

**Update**

You asked about conditionals so this is what I would propose

```
ndoc = Nokogiri::XML(doc)
namespaces = ndoc.collect_namespaces

response = ndoc.xpath("//CONTENT/dms:ComplexResponse", namespaces)

if response.xpath("self::node()[@ErrorCode != '' and @ErrorDescription != '']").any?
  response.xpath("@ErrorCode | @ErrorDescription")
  .each_with_object({}) do |e,obj| 
    obj[e.name] = e.text
  end
else
  response.xpath('dms:Element/@Name | dms:Element/text()',namespaces)
    .each_slice(2)
    .map {|s| s.map(&:text)}.to_h
end
```

This checks to see if there is an ErrorCode and and ErrorDescription if so then Hash as originally proposed. If Not then it returns all the dms:Elements as a `Hash` so `{"DMSVERSION"=>"2.7"}` in this case [Functional Example](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/NokogiriParsing)

Comment: For a better understanding of XPath check out different examples [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @3limin4t0r added a reference of my own which I find to be a bit more concise (mostly because I despise MS documentation)

Comment: Thank you very much! It is a perfect explanation.

Comment: @engineersmnky I'm not a fan of the MS documentation either, but de MDN documentation for XPath is even worse.

Comment: How can I check if the attributes ErrorCode and ErrorDescription exist?

Comment: I mean I need a condition that tells me if the attributes are there or not

Comment: @AlessandroLopresti I assume you want to check the "ErrorCode" from the resulting hash. You can simply call `result['ErrorCode']` if no error code is present `nil` will be returned, the same applies for "ErrorDescription". You have to assign the result of the answer to a variable though.

Comment: @AlessandroLopresti what do you want to do if they are not present? Did you want to select something else?

Comment: @AlessandroLopresti updated to show conditional logic